# Is the average area of a random $n$-dimensional convex hull decreasing with $n$?

Tags: area, polytopes, convex-hulls

I calculate the area of the convex hulls of $n+1$ random points in a unit $n$-cube for $n$ = $3$ to $10$. (I use scipy.spatial.convexhull).

For each $n$, I generate $1000$ sets to get the average area and I find that the average area decreases fast with increasing $n$.

Is this result expected? I can’t wrap my head around why. (If not, I’ve probably misunderstood the scipy library.)

Since the area of a unit $n$-cube is $2n$, I kind of expected the area to increase with n in my experiment.

Comment: What are you calling "area" in nD ?

Comment: You might find this video interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo-qYV-fZVM

Comment: Your final remark, that "the area of a unit $n$-cube is $2n$" suggests a possible misunderstanding.  The *sides* of a unit $n$-cube are unit $(n-1)$-cubes.  For example, a $4$ cube (tesseract) has eight sides that are $3$-cubes, sixteen vertices (corners), $32$ exterior edges (line segments between adjacent corners), and $24$ exterior faces (that are unit squares).  Trying to interpret the claim that the area of a unit $4$-cube is $8$ requires us to assume you are treating the eight cubic sides as contributing each a unit of area, which seems dimensionally improper.

Comment: I thought that the area property of the scipy convex hull object would be the sum of all 2d face's areas. But thanks to your comments I understand it seems to be the sum of the n-1 dimensional volumes. If I use the library to calculate the convex hull of a unit n-cube, the area property of the object is 2n. (That result was what made me incorrectly think that the area was 2n for a unit n-cube). So if it's a sum of volumes, I understand that it will decrease with n since a random point easily can make the volume very "thin" in at least one dimension. Does that make sense?

Comment: You haven't considered answering my question; it's your right... but consider that understanding the "mathematical being" you are faced to(here the "area" with quotes) is maybe the key...

Comment: Jean Marie: My previous comment was aimed to you all. I'm sorry I was unclear – it seems to be the key indeed! The "area" I was thinking of was to somehow get all 2-d surfaces of the n-dimensional convex hull and sum their areas. But that was not the "area" the library calculated, but rather the "surface volume".

Answer (score 1):

It is expected for the average area of the convex hulls of random points in a unit n-cube to decrease with increasing n.

As n increases, the number of points in the cube also increases, which makes it more likely that the points will be distributed more evenly across the cube. With more evenly distributed points, the convex hull will enclose a smaller area of the cube, leading to a smaller average area.

Another way to think about it is as the dimension of the cube increases, the volume of the cube increases exponentially while the surface area of the cube increases only linearly. So, as the dimension increases, the points are more likely to be closer to the interior of the cube, resulting in smaller convex hull area.

It is also important to note that the function you used from scipy library is returning the area of the convex hull and not the area of the cube, and the area of the convex hull is generally smaller than the area of the cube.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to trying think in this many dimensions and I have troubles visualising your explanation. Wouldn't more faces lead to more 2-d shapes adding to the total area? I might very well be too stuck in a 3d mindset, and summing the areas of 2-d shapes in a n-dimensional convex hull maybe isn't what I think it is.